# How to create an Appx package from a QT UWP Project

Tags: qt, uwp, appx

I've created a program using QT Creator which generates a UWP (Universal Windows 10 App). It will run and I can install it using the Add-AppxPackage -Register AppManifest.XML from within PowerShell.

However, I wish to upload it to the Windows Store and I can't find any guidance on creating the Appx[upload] package that you need to distribute the App. Add-AppxPackage doesn't seem to generate an intermediate Appx file.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: I don't know much about QT Creator, but I guess you need to use one of the tools Microsoft recommends for UWP packaging https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/14/apps-built-using-the-desktop-bridge-now-available-in-the-windows-store/

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it appears you can use the MakeAppx command that comes with Visual Studio 2015. Running windeployqt to setup the folder followed by MakeAppx (from Visual Studio Developer command prompt) generates an Appx file. Unfortunately it's not signed so you still can't do anything with it. I tried signing it with signtool and my standard code signing certificate but it didn't work.

Comment: QT Creator automatically generates an AppManifest.XML file but you have to go in and edit it to set the right: PublisherName, and the publisher in the 'identify' section has to exactly match the publisher in the certificate, including any location information in the certificate.